# Is it possible to use angular material CSS without creating the angular app?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a vanilla Javascript app. I can't really turn it into an angular app. However I would like to apply angular material CSS within it.

Comment: You can create Angular-Element web-component and then you can use it in your every JavaScript world. In this approach your material design is already in form of JavaScript so that you can reuse it everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO your best pick would be the official Material Design Components library made by Google themselves which implement the same specs and is made for pure JavaScript.

Components - https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/

Getting Started - https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

[Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/) allows you to use the appearance of Material Design without having to depend on the particular implementation for any framework.